# I want to use the Google Analytics API to call the data, but there is a related error

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

According to this document:https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php
Select the PHP language step Demo under Service Applications and build according to the steps in the development document. The following error will appear when you perform the fourth step:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 35: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to [www.googleapis.com:443](http://www.googleapis.com:443)  (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in D:\phpstudy\phpstudy_pro\WWW\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:186         as shown in error1.png[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsP38.png)

Comment: Have you tried searching for this error message there are like 150 questions relating to this error message alone.

Comment: @DaImTo  I have tried to search the relevant questions, but there seems to be no right answer for me. And when I follow the example you gave me, the error seems to change
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: Curl error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed. The most likely reason for the failure is that cURL was unable  to rewind the body of the request and subsequent retries resulted in the same error. Turn on the debug option to see  what went wrong. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47204 for more information.

Comment: Yeah but i know this sample it works.   Meah your going to make me install PHP on my machine again i can feel it.   Let me ping the team see if anyone has time to look at it.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I follow the code for this example: 
 https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php#helloanalyticsphp

Comment: This isn't a Google analytics question this is a PHP question.  You need to fix your issue with php.   WIthout seeing your code its hard for me to help.